# OSX: Watching tempeture trends based on Ambient Tempeture

Tags: mac-osx, physical-environment

So I noticed a temperature monitor cleverly labeled "Ambient." Knowing that the sensor is inside my computer, I can get a decent temperature check on my overly hot dorm room if I check it as soon as I wake my computer from sleep. I was curious if there was some way of logging temperature data for different parts of the day, ignoring the times where the processors are making the ambient temperature rise?

Comment: Why not just buy a thermometer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible via SNMP. There are plenty of guides on the Internet how to set up SNMP on OS X, including this one: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20884?viewlocale=en_US from Apple.

The next way would be to set up mrtg/cacti to monitor the sensor.

If you're looking for a GUI utility, you can for example Temperature Monitor
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12381/temperature-monitor